# Replace a value in a row with a value in another row in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like so:

| id | startValue | endValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 11a |
| 1 | 554 | 22b |
| 2 | null | 33c |
| 2 | 6743 | 44d |

Assume that we'll always have 2 rows with the same `id`, one where `startValue` has value and another where `startValue` is always null.
I'd like to replace the null values in the `startValue` with `startValue-10`, where the `startValue` is taken from the row with same id where `startValue` is not null.

| id | startValue | endValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 544 | 11a |
| 1 | 554 | 22b |
| 2 | 6733 | 33c |
| 2 | 6743 | 44d |

Sample data frame:

```
val df = Seq(
("1", null, "11a"),
("1", 554, "22b"),
("2", null, "33c"),
("2", 6743, "44d"),
).toDF("id", "startValue", "endValue")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Try to provide more information about what you already tried. Stackoverflow is full of answers on how to perform a join between two dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `coalesce` the nulls with the other `startValue` found in the same partition of `id`, minus 10:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "startValue",
    coalesce($"startValue", max($"startValue").over(Window.partitionBy("id")) - 10)
)

df2.show
+---+----------+--------+
| id|startValue|endValue|
+---+----------+--------+
|  1|       544|     11a|
|  1|       554|     22b|
|  2|      6733|     33c|
|  2|      6743|     44d|
+---+----------+--------+
```

Comment: or, take a `lead()` since your in OP's case df just has 2 rows for an id.